# CSS Height percentage after padding not right

Tags: css

I have a page with two rows which should be fluid and 100% high and wide and have positioned the rows absolutely.

Here is the code:

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div class="toprow">
        <p>Top</p>
    </div>
    <div class="bottomrow">
        <div class="inner">
            <p>Bottom</p>
        </div>    
    </div>
</div>

.toprow {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 45%;
    width: 100%;
    background: green;
}
.bottomrow {
    position: absolute;
    top: 55%;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    background: red;
}

.inner{
    width: 98%;
    height: 95%;
    padding: 1%;
    background: #00f;
}

.inner p{
    background: white;
}
```

On the second row's inner wrapper I have added a padding of 1%. So if there is one percent padding either side, I now need the width of the div inside the wrapper to be 98%. Logical.

Why doesn't this work on the height? If you look at my jsfiddle below, you will see that the height needs to be set to just over 95% to fit the wrapper, even though there is just 1% padding on the top and bottom.

https://jsfiddle.net/d86o8L02/1/

Comment: Instead of `width: 98%` do `box-sizing: border-box; width: 100%;`. Also check if parent has it's own height specified. If no - than 1% from 0px height is still 0px.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the html and body's margin to zero and then change the box-model to [`box-sizing:border-box`](http://www.paulirish.com/2012/box-sizing-border-box-ftw/) to include the padding in the sizing:

https://jsfiddle.net/d86o8L02/2/

```css
html, body {
    margin:0; /* < remove default margins */
}
.toprow {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 45%;
    width: 100%;
    background: green;
}
.bottomrow {
    position: absolute;
    top: 55%;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    background: red;
}
.inner{
    width: 100%; /* < make 100% */
    height: 100%;  /* < make 100% */
    padding: 1%;
    background: #00f;
    box-sizing: border-box; /* < change box model */
}
.inner p {
    background: white;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
    <div class="toprow">
        <p>Top</p>
    </div>
    <div class="bottomrow">
        <div class="inner">
            <p>Bottom</p>
        </div>    
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the box-sizing property.

```
   -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
   -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
```